# How to interpret the 'rational' value for FramesPerSecond metadata in some movie formats?

Tags: openimageio

The plugin for GIFs or Movies defines a *FramesPerSecond* attribute of type

```
int[2] (rational)
```

What does that mean? One possible interpretation I came up with is that the second item in the array holds the fractional part. Is that so? If yes, why not just use a `float` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Rational" means it's a fraction. The float value would be (approximately) `float(value[0])/float(value[1])`.

The reason I said "approximately", and the reason it's not a float to begin with, is because floating point numbers cannot exactly represent many useful fractions.